# Unexpected end of JSON input when assigning json data to a html element as an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I need to assign `JSON` data as a html attribute like this, so that I can retrieve the value with `onClick` event.

```
<button class="chat" topic-chats=${JSON.stringify(innerTopicJSON.Chats)}></button>
```

Here is the `innerTopicJSON.Chats` value
[image]

And here is my onClick event block of code

```
$('.chat').click(event => {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.stopPropagation();

    let chats = JSON.parse($(event.target).attr('topic-chats'));
    // some code .....
})
```

But it returns an error ! ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input***

What's going wrong here, please ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need Quotes in html element attribute.

```
<button class="chat" topic-chats="however json with your language"></button>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But when i use quotation, don't get the full json !
By the way, my button element is returned from a function like this "return `<button>...</button>`"

Comment: is it angular??

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="chat" topic-chats="chats response here">Jivo chat</button>
```

add these javascript code

```
 let innerTopicJSON = {chats:'hello message'}; // smaple json response 
        let jsonstring=innerTopicJSON.chats;  
        $('.chat').attr('topic-chats',jsonstring);
```

Comment: Thats not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]**

In my case, JSON.parse() function stop parsing when find any empty space! I don't know why its happening.

So i need to encode every json property - SendAt,UserName when push to database. It solves my issue.

I am using node for backend and firebase for database.

If anyone face the problem, may be it will helpful.

-----Happy Coding------